# android Handler to wait for message for a period of time

Tags: android

I have a scenario where a thread waits for a message with Looper.Prepare() and Looper.loop(). When a button clicked in UI, sending a message to Handler notifying the click of button. If no button clicked for 2 minutes, I want to break the looper, how to achieve it ? I tried using Timer and timertask but nothing happens

The code is as follows in the non-ui Thread

```
   Looper.prepare();
      uiHandler = new Handler() {
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      // Act on the message
        if (msg.obj.contains("DONE")) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Done task",                   
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }     
      }
     }
  Looper.loop();
```

From UI thread :

```
 btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.obj = "DONE";
            uiHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `== "DONE"` <= it would be better to learn java's basics first ...

Comment: Call `Looper.quit()` when appropriate.

Comment: how to notify looper that  2 mints completed is the problem.. i am facing...

Comment: use `Handler#sendEmptyMessageDelayed`

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using handlers `postDelayed` method

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Done task",                   
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
uihandler.postDelayed(runnable , 2*60*1000);
```

and in onClickListener use `removeCallback` method

```
uiHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Comment: doesn't matter, it depends on where you define handler and it seems you defined it on MainActivity and it will be handled on MainActivity's thread